# Multiple jquery ajax api holds the last value and performs success function using only that value

Tags: jquery, ajax

I would like to iterate over a class of elements and perform an ajax call using some information of each particular element and do some manipulation with the results.

Here is my jquery code

```
$(".Topic").each(function () {
    var identify = $(this).attr('id');
    var prestart = identify.indexOf('_');
    var start = prestart + 1;
    var end = identify.length;
    var position = identify.substr(start, end);

    var trend = $("#Topic_" + position).text();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Results.aspx/CheckIfScheduled",
        data: "{\"Trend\":" + "\"" + trend + "\"" + "}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (results) {
            var str = results, obj = JSON.parse(str);
            if (str.Scheduled == true) {
                $("#IsSch_" + position).text(str.Date);
                $("#Sch_" + position).hide();
                $("#Cal_" + position).hide();
            }
        },
        error: alert("Error")
    });

});
```

The back-end code just returns a serialized string which I use in my success function.
The problem I am having is that it iterates through each class elements first and once it's done iterating it starts doing all the success function instances using the last value that it has stored.

I've tried setting async:false but I keep getting the error "unexpected token o"

Comment: It seems odd to me that your ajax call is wrap within an .each. This means that for each ".Topic" class, it will make an ajax call. Is that what you want?

Comment: The Topic class has label elements with Topic_ ids which tell me which label I am looking at since I am using a asp:repeater. I want to traverse each of those labels, send it's text value through the ajax call, and get the results back to use to set some other elements within that row.

Comment: Can you try moving the code within the success function OUTSIDE the ajax call and then add "async:false" to the call?

Comment: The problem is in your position, the moment you send your ajax asyncronously your position is the last one for tha last call. When you receive the response your code position is the last one. To solve that the first thing that go to my mind is to send the position on the request and receive it back in the success.

Comment: @RogérioEduardoBarreto, it could be that the .each is running faster than the .ajax and things went out of sync.

Comment: @ChiChan Yep, once he is using async calls, the loop runs to the end before the first response as the "position" variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know if it would work but you could try to place a position inside the success callback ...

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Results.aspx/CheckIfScheduled",
    data: "{\"Trend\":" + "\"" + trend + "\"" + "}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (results) {
        var positionInner = position;
        var str = results, obj = JSON.parse(str);
        if (str.Scheduled == true) {
            $("#IsSch_" + positionInner).text(str.Date);
            $("#Sch_" + positionInner).hide();
            $("#Cal_" + positionInner).hide();
        }
    },
    error: alert("Error")
});
```

Comment: Your answer works! I was also curious as to why I was getting the error when I would use either async/sync calls and it seems that I was just trying to parse an object which didn't need parsing hence the error. Just to clarify this can be done using my original code minus `var str = results, obj = JSON.parse(str);`, changing `str.Scheduled == true` to `results.d.Scheduled == true` , `text(results.d.Date)`and adding the `async:false`.

Comment: Yeah, the manual parsing of Json isnt necessary if the formting of the server respects 100% JSON specification, (If the server uses ' instead of " it would not parse... The async:false would also resolve your problem but it would freeze your UI until you have all the responses.